# linq join 1 to many get first record

Tags: linq

I have 2 list:

List1:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

List2:

```
ID   Name
1  Jason
1  Jim
2  Mike
3  Phil
```

I like to join both of these but get only the first record from list2 for a given ID:
The end result would be

```
ID Name
1  Jason
2  Mike
3  Phil
```

I tried the following but was not successful:

```
    var lst = (from lst1 in list1
               join lst2 in list2
               on lst1.ID equals lst2.ID).ToList().First();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get this result with what the [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) calls ["Cross Join with Group Join"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9). Combine that with `First()` to get just one item from the group.

```
var lst = (
    from lst1 in list1
    join lst2 in list2 on lst1.ID equals lst2.ID into lstGroup
    select lstGroup.First()
);
```

**Example:** http://ideone.com/V0sRO

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, for supplying the test harness. I started with what you built and added my own twist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```cs
var lst = list1
    // Select distinct IDs that are in both lists:
    .Where(lst1 => list2
        .Select(lst2 => lst2.ID)
        .Contains(lst1.ID))
    .Distinct()
    // Select items in list 2 matching the IDs above:
    .Select(lst1 => list2
        .Where(lst2 => lst2.ID == lst1.ID)
        .First());
```

**Example:** http://ideone.com/6egSc

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping list2 by ID first and then selecting the first item from each group.  After that, do the join and select what you want.

```
var uniqueIDList2 = list2.GroupBy(p => p.ID)
                         .Select(p => p.First());

var result = from lst1 in list1
             join lst2 in uniqueIDList2 on lst1.ID equals lst2.ID
             select new { lst1.ID, lst2.Name };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
var query = from lst1 in list1
            let first = list2.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == lst1.Id)
            where first != null
            select first;
```

Or if you wanted to know about items that could not be located in list2:

```
var query = from lst1 in list1
            let first = list2.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == lst1.Id)
            select first ?? new { Id = 0, Name = "Not Found" };
```