# LINQ get first value in given list

Tags: linq

I have a list(mainlist) with the following

```
PsID  Nominprsn
----  ---------
1     James
2     Troy
2     William
3     Mike
4     Jason
4     Hendry
```

I need to get the first name from a given `PsID`
so the result would be as such

```
PsID  Nominprsn
----  ---------
1     James
2     Troy
3     Mike
4     Jason
```

I tried the following but was not successful as I didn't know how to get the first `PsID`:

```
var proglis = (from ts in mainlist
               group ts by new { ts.PsID, Nominprsn} into grp
               select new {grp.Key.PsID grp.Key.Nominprsn}).ToList();
```

Comment: How is this different than [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088608/linq-join-1-to-many-get-first-record)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the first item from each group use this query:

```
var query = mainlist.GroupBy(o => o.PsID)
                    .Select(g => new { PsID = g.Key, g.First().Nominprsn })
                    .ToList();
```

This will return the same results you've shown in your question. The result will be an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types with properties named `PsID` and `Nominprsn`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should do it:

```
var proglis = (from ts in mainlist
               group ts by ts.PsID into grp
               select new 
               {
                 Id = grp.Key,
                 Name = grp.First().Nominprsn
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: If you use `FirstOrDefault` like that, you'll get a NullReferenceException if there are no items in the list.

Comment: @Ray Since it is group, there are always elements in the group, otherwise group wouldn't exist. If mainlist is empty, it will also not give NullReferenceException, because there will be no groups. I've tried it out and it works fine. Can you give me some example where it throws NullReferenceException?

Comment: I was talking of the general case of `FirstOrDefault().Member`. In your case you should just use `First()`.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe try Distinct or DistinctBy(o => o.Key.PsID)